# failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream -- nginx/gunicorn connection via 127.0.0.1

Tags: docker, nginx, localhost, gunicorn, nginx-reverse-proxy

Below are the important details:

**Dockerfile for nginx build**

```
FROM nginx:latest
EXPOSE 443
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

**Nginx.conf**

```
events {}
http {
  client_max_body_size 1000M;
  server {
    server_name _;
    location / {
      proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    }

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate cert/name.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key cert/name.key;
  }
}
```

**Nginx docker command**

```
docker run -dit -p 0.0.0.0:443:443 -v /etc/cert/:/etc/nginx/cert <MY NGINX CONTAINER> nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

**Docker command to start gunicorn server**

```
docker run -dit -p 127.0.0.1:8000:8000 <My FASTAPI CONTAINER> gunicorn -w 3 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b 127.0.0.1:8000 server:app
```

Other details:

- I expose port 8000 in my Fastapi container docker build
- I run nginx docker command right before the gunicorn docker command
- I am currently testing with python requests library and have turned verify=False for the SSL configuration

Edit:
My issue related most directly to this post:
[From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Binding to 0.0.0.0:8000 for my gunicorn run and adding the tag --network="host" to my docker run nginx command solved my issue

Comment: Try running your `gunicorn` command with `-b 0.0.0.0:8000` instead. From the docker container's perspective, the port needs to be open outwards.

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is a special IP address, which in Docker typically means the current container (not another container or non-container processes on the host).  I've linked this to two questions, one with a very similar setup using Docker Compose and a second describing the manual `docker network create`/`docker run --net` options you need running outside of Compose.

Comment: Thank you for the links! I saw the docker compose question; it looks very similar to mine, except the resolution they came to is essentially the setup I gave to my question. The docker network question doesn't solve my core issue, but could be a workaround if I don't get this working.

On the 127.0.0.1 issue -- that's helpful, thank you! I found the following question that seems related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Would adding --network="host" in both my docker commands fix my issue?